# Deleting certain file type attachments in a specific channel?

Tags: discord, python-3.7, discord.py

I'm trying to add certain files from being posted to the general channel as we have designated channels for certain attachments, clips, videos, music, etc. I'm fine on getting the bot to recognize links, however, having a hard time getting it to recognize attachments, more specifically, .mp4 attachments.

I added a whitelist of acceptable attachments in an array, then try and check the message author attachment to see if it's okay to post, if its an .mp4 it should be deleted.

The try function is within the on_message event decorator.

```
whiteList = ['bmp','jpeg','jpg','png']
    try:
        for attachment in message.attachments:
            #Get general channel ID
            channel = client.get_channel(521376573245358081)
            if message.channel is channel and attachment['filename'].split('.')[-1] not in whiteList:
                await message.delete()
                botsMessage = await channel.send("{0.mention} Please refrain from posting videos in General. You may post them in #videos".format(message.author))
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await botsMessage.delete()
    except:
        print('Unknown error')
```

No error comes of this as when I test this the attachment remains, the bot passes over the function and prints the console message (used for debugging to make sure the code reaches that far). Any suggestions?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but just FYI for anyone else, it's generally not a good idea to use bare `try ... except` statements. At least do `try ... except Exception as e: print(e)` so you get the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
attachment['filename'].split('.')[-1]
```

You treated `attachment` as an dictionary that has a key called `filename`.
You should have treated `attachment` as an object that has a property called `filename` as follows:

```
attachment.filename.split('.')[-1]
```

Also, you should `break` the loop whenever the message is deleted,

```
# ...
botsMessage = await channel.send("{0.mention} Please refrain from posting videos in General. You may post them in #videos".format(message.author))
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await botsMessage.delete()
break
# ...
```

in the event that the user have sent mutiple video files, the loop will still continue even after you delete the message. Which may cause it to try to delete a deleted message
The `break` statement prevents the above from happening.

Comment: Are you sick of answering my questions yet? lol, THANK YOU AGAIN! Works great.